# How to make variable case sensative when doing a powershell find replace in Word

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a document that can be sent to new employees with their new account info.  I have the script set the variables which works and generate a password which works and then it does a find/replace in a word template and then save as, which works.  The issue I have is that the values of variables that I set all seem to be converted 'ToUpper' when they are find/replaced in the Word file.  This is problematic especially when it comes to the password variable.  Can anyone pick out why it is converting it to upper when it is applied to the Word file?

```
[string]$FName = Read-Host -Prompt 'First Name'
[string]$LName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Last Name'
[Int32]$EmpID = Read-Host -Prompt 'Employee ID'

$Name = $FName + ' ' + $LName
$UserName = ($FName.Substring(0,1)+$LName).ToLower()
$Email = ($FName.Substring(0,1)+$LName + 'redacted').ToLower()


#Generates a random password for the user.
function Get-RandomCharacters($length, $characters) {
    $random = 1..$length | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Maximum $characters.length }
    $private:ofs=""
    return [String]$characters[$random]
}
 
function Scramble-String([string]$inputString){     
    $characterArray = $inputString.ToCharArray()   
    $scrambledStringArray = $characterArray | Get-Random -Count $characterArray.Length     
    $outputString = -join $scrambledStringArray
    return $outputString 
}
 
$password = Get-RandomCharacters -length 3 -characters 'abcdefghiklmnprstuvwxyz'
$password += Get-RandomCharacters -length 1 -characters 'ABCDEFGHKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ'
$password += Get-RandomCharacters -length 2 -characters '1234567890'
$password += Get-RandomCharacters -length 2 -characters '!$%&=?@#'
 

 
[string]$password = Scramble-String $password
Write-Host $password

#Sets criteria for find/replace and path variable.  Eg #FindEmail is replaced with $ReplaceEmail
$Document = "C:\testing\template.docx"
$FindName = "FULLNAME"
$ReplaceName = "$Name" 
$FindFname = "FNAME"
$ReplaceFname = "$FName"
$FindUPN = "UNAME"
$ReplaceUPN = "$UserName"
$FindPasswd = "PASSWD"
$ReplacePasswd = "$password"
$FindEmail = "UPN"
$ReplaceEmail = "$Email"
$FindEmpID = "EMPLOYEEID"
$ReplaceEmpID = "$EmpID"
$SaveAS = "C:\testing\" + $UserName + '.docx'
    
    $ReplaceAll = 2
    $FindContinue = 1
    $MatchCase = $False
    $MatchWholeWord = $True
    $MatchWildcards = $False
    $MatchSoundsLike = $False
    $MatchAllWordForms = $False
    $Forward = $True
    $Wrap = $FindContinue
    $Format = $True

    $Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $False
   
    $OpenDoc = $Word.Documents.Open($Document)
    $Selection = $Word.Selection
   

   #Replaces Full Name
    $Selection.Find.Execute(
    $FindName,
    $MatchCase,
    $MatchWholeWord,
    $MatchWildcards,
    $MatchSoundsLike,
    $MatchAllWordForms,
    $Forward,
    $Wrap,
    $Format,
    $ReplaceName,
    $ReplaceAll
    ) | Out-Null

    #Replaces First Name
    $Selection.Find.Execute(
    $FindFname,
    $MatchCase,
    $MatchWholeWord,
    $MatchWildcards,
    $MatchSoundsLike,
    $MatchAllWordForms,
    $Forward,
    $Wrap,
    $Format,
    $ReplaceFname,
    $ReplaceAll
    ) | Out-Null

    #Replaces Email address
    $Selection.Find.Execute(
    $FindUPN,
    $MatchCase,
    $MatchWholeWord,
    $MatchWildcards,
    $MatchSoundsLike,
    $MatchAllWordForms,
    $Forward,
    $Wrap,
    $Format,
    $ReplaceUPN,
    $ReplaceAll
    ) | Out-Null

    #Replaces Password
    $Selection.Find.Execute(
    $FindPasswd,
    $MatchCase,
    $MatchWholeWord,
    $MatchWildcards,
    $MatchSoundsLike,
    $MatchAllWordForms,
    $Forward,
    $Wrap,
    $Format,
   $ReplacePasswd,
    $ReplaceAll
    ) | Out-Null

    #Replaces Email
    $Selection.Find.Execute(
    $FindEmail,
    $MatchCase,
    $MatchWholeWord,
    $MatchWildcards,
    $MatchSoundsLike,
    $MatchAllWordForms,
    $Forward,
    $Wrap,
    $Format,
   $ReplaceEmail,
    $ReplaceAll
    ) | Out-Null

    
    #Replaces Password
    $Selection.Find.Execute(
    $FindPasswd,
    $MatchCase,
    $MatchWholeWord,
    $MatchWildcards,
    $MatchSoundsLike,
    $MatchAllWordForms,
    $Forward,
    $Wrap,
    $Format,
   $ReplacePasswd,
    $ReplaceAll
    ) | Out-Null

    
    #Replaces EmployeeID
    $Selection.Find.Execute(
    $FindEmpID,
    $MatchCase,
    $MatchWholeWord,
    $MatchWildcards,
    $MatchSoundsLike,
    $MatchAllWordForms,
    $Forward,
    $Wrap,
    $Format,
    $ReplaceEmpID,
    $ReplaceAll
    ) | Out-Null

    $OpenDoc.SaveAs($SaveAS)
   
    $OpenDoc.Close()
    $Word.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I swear I googled and looked at the man page but somehow I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my "Google-fu" turned up something pretty quick that I think is relevant. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute#remarks). From the article:

'Also, if MatchCase is False, occurrences of the search text that are uppercase will be replaced with an uppercase version of the replacement text, regardless of the case of the replacement text. Using the previous example, occurrences of "ABC" are replaced with "XYZ".'

So, to test, either change the case in your template or change `"$MatchCase = $false"` to true.

Comment: Also, I searched on Bing, actually, for "selection execute match case" and found that link as result number 3.